# Last Executed Query through Application in HANA

Tags: hana

I am looking for the last executed query and time taken in SAP HANA from an application. I know that we have something like `SYS.M_SQL_PLAN_CACHE` which will give the queries executed directly in HANA, but I am looking for those executed through some Java application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable user-specific trace for the user with which you connect your Java-app to HANA.

Starting with SAP HANA 2.0 SPS 03 it is possible to restrict traced statements by user and/or by connection ID along with statements hash.

Here are the examples how to enable trace by different criteria:

```
-- to enable traces
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') 
SET 
('traceprofile_<context>','application_user') = '<application user>', 
('traceprofile_<context>','sql_user') = '<database user>', 
('traceprofile_<context>','connection_id') = '<connection id>',
('traceprofile_<context>','statement_hash') = '<statement_hash of DB>', 
('traceprofile_<context>', '<component1>') = '<trace level>', 
('traceprofile_<context>', '<component2>') = '<trace level>' 
with reconfigure;

-- to disable traces
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') 
UNSET ('traceprofile_<context>') with reconfigure;
```

Traces are stored in */usr/sap/{SID}/{HDB_instance}/{host}/trace*, read more in [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/08/user-specific-database-traces-filtered-by-connection_id-and-statement_hash-as-of-hana-version-2.0-sps03/)